# Get co-ordinate points of image after rotation and translation?

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation, collision-detection, translate-animation

I currently draw some images (obstacles) to the canvas but I perform context.rotate() and context.translate() before I draw them (at 0,0 point after the point translation).

I need to create collisions between an image that is drawn after these obstacles (the image co-ordinates are user controlled, e.g. vehicle).

Before I implemented rotate and translate, I would perform collisions based on the mid points of the vehicle and obstacle at the right time. However I have no idea how I can get the actual "un-translated" and "un-rotated" co-ordinate points of the obstacles.

Note: for each obstacle, I know the variable that I rotate and translate by, the problem is that I perform rotate and translate multiple times after one another like this:

```
// set origin to center
context.translate(canvasX, canvasY);

context.rotate(i/30);
context.translate(20,10);

if(toggle < 20) {
    size++;
    if(size > 10) {
      size = 10;
    }
    drawImageRot(image_red, 0, 0, ((image_red.height / img_max) * size), ((image_red.width / img_max) * size), 30);
    //circle('red', size);
}
// rotate + move along x
context.rotate(y / 40);
context.translate(40, 0);

if(toggle > 100 && toggle < 120) {
    size++;
    if(size > 10) {
      size = 10;
    }
    drawImageRot(image_red, 0, 0, ((image_red.height / img_max) * size), ((image_red.width / img_max) * size), 30);
    //circle('red', size);
}
context.rotate(z / 20);
context.translate(5, 5);

if(toggle > 200 && toggle < 220) {
    size++;
    if(size > 10) {
      size = 10;
    }
    drawImageRot(image_red, 0, 0, ((image_red.height / img_max) * size), ((image_red.width / img_max) * size), 30);
}
```

So by the third image - I would have done 4 different translations and 3 different rotations.

How can I get the co-ordinate points of the "obstacles"? or is there anyway I can easily check if the two images are overlapping without requiring the co-ordinate points?

### EDIT:

I decided to split my "collision" detection so that I check just after I do drawImageRot() like this:

```
// set origin to center
context.translate(canvasX, canvasY);

context.rotate(i/30);
context.translate(20,10);

if(toggle < 20) {
    size++;
    if(size > 10) {
      size = 10;
    }
    drawImageRot(image_red, 0, 0, ((image_red.height / img_max) * size), ((image_red.width / img_max) * size), 30);
    // HERE I NEED TO SET my currentX and currentY points! But how?
    currentX = 0;
    currentY = 0;

    if((Math.abs(currentX - playerX) <= 20 && Math.abs(currentY - playerY) <= 20)) {
      drawCollision(currentX, currentY, size);
      isCollision = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I may have found my answer, @simonsarris has created a transform.js class to help translate/rotate 'x,y' points:

https://github.com/simonsarris/Canvas-tutorials/blob/master/transform.js

With example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/b2fEX/

```
// LIBRARY from:
// https://github.com/simonsarris/Canvas-tutorials/blob/master/transform.js
// code below

function Transform() {
  this.reset();
}

Transform.prototype.reset = function() {
  this.m = [1,0,0,1,0,0];
};

Transform.prototype.multiply = function(matrix) {
  var m11 = this.m[0] * matrix.m[0] + this.m[2] * matrix.m[1];
  var m12 = this.m[1] * matrix.m[0] + this.m[3] * matrix.m[1];

  var m21 = this.m[0] * matrix.m[2] + this.m[2] * matrix.m[3];
  var m22 = this.m[1] * matrix.m[2] + this.m[3] * matrix.m[3];

  var dx = this.m[0] * matrix.m[4] + this.m[2] * matrix.m[5] + this.m[4];
  var dy = this.m[1] * matrix.m[4] + this.m[3] * matrix.m[5] + this.m[5];

  this.m[0] = m11;
  this.m[1] = m12;
  this.m[2] = m21;
  this.m[3] = m22;
  this.m[4] = dx;
  this.m[5] = dy;
};

Transform.prototype.invert = function() {
  var d = 1 / (this.m[0] * this.m[3] - this.m[1] * this.m[2]);
  var m0 = this.m[3] * d;
  var m1 = -this.m[1] * d;
  var m2 = -this.m[2] * d;
  var m3 = this.m[0] * d;
  var m4 = d * (this.m[2] * this.m[5] - this.m[3] * this.m[4]);
  var m5 = d * (this.m[1] * this.m[4] - this.m[0] * this.m[5]);
  this.m[0] = m0;
  this.m[1] = m1;
  this.m[2] = m2;
  this.m[3] = m3;
  this.m[4] = m4;
  this.m[5] = m5;
};

Transform.prototype.rotate = function(rad) {
  var c = Math.cos(rad);
  var s = Math.sin(rad);
  var m11 = this.m[0] * c + this.m[2] * s;
  var m12 = this.m[1] * c + this.m[3] * s;
  var m21 = this.m[0] * -s + this.m[2] * c;
  var m22 = this.m[1] * -s + this.m[3] * c;
  this.m[0] = m11;
  this.m[1] = m12;
  this.m[2] = m21;
  this.m[3] = m22;
};

Transform.prototype.translate = function(x, y) {
  this.m[4] += this.m[0] * x + this.m[2] * y;
  this.m[5] += this.m[1] * x + this.m[3] * y;
};

Transform.prototype.scale = function(sx, sy) {
  this.m[0] *= sx;
  this.m[1] *= sx;
  this.m[2] *= sy;
  this.m[3] *= sy;
};

Transform.prototype.transformPoint = function(px, py) {
  var x = px;
  var y = py;
  px = x * this.m[0] + y * this.m[2] + this.m[4];
  py = x * this.m[1] + y * this.m[3] + this.m[5];
  return [px, py];
};


// CODE:
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(50,50,50,50);

var t = new Transform();
ctx.translate(50,0)
ctx.rotate(1);
t.translate(50,0);
t.rotate(1);

ctx.fillRect(50,50,50,50);
var pt = t.transformPoint(50,50);
alert('top left of translated rectangle is: ' + pt);
```